# python webkit geolocation error - permission

Tags: python, gps, webkit, openlayers-3, raspberry-pi2

i'm working on a project and using python gtk and webkit to create a simple browser on a raspberry with GPS.

```
import gtk, webkit

win = gtk.Window()
win.fullscreen()
win.connect('destroy', lambda w: gtk.main_quit())

scroller = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
web = webkit.WebView()

web.open("http://localhost/geolocation.html")
win.add(scroller)
scroller.add(web)

win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

and html with openlayers in order to show on a map the geolocation.
the main problem is when im running the code with xamp from my pc 
the geolocation works perfectly, but when im running it from raspberry
with webkit i get geolocation error, i think the problem is the Geolocation Policy on webkit, how to give permission? or there is any other way to get directly the coordinates from GPS and passing it to geolocation of openlayers?

Comment: Any more details on the error?

Comment: no! it just the geolocation error from javascript. I'm sure the problem is from webkit permission, because even google geolocation don't work.

Comment: An error is normally copy pasteable. Does it really just say "geolocation error"? That it doesn't work on google does not guarantee that it is a permission issue.

Comment: i don't know how to show the error with webkit.